# Can I have ipsec-tools working for non standard ports?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, ipsec

I was trying to set up a manually-keyed connection via ipsec-tools between two ubuntu 12.04 servers, following this simple [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IPSecHowTo), but one of that two servers, has just a range of ports 3000 .. 3100 available, because of firewall constriction.

Is it possible set them up non standard port and if yes how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPsec itself doesn't use any ports. If you are willing to setup manually as described in the tutorial it should work.

You need ports for automatic key exchange via racoon or another IKE daemon or maybe if you use NAT. These ports are 500/udp and 4500/udp by default and can by changed in racoon config file

```
    (maybe)    /etc/racoon/racoon.conf
```

Check the manpage

```
    man racoon.conf
```

for the listen section (Listening Port Specification).